# How does WPF determine focus?

Tags: wpf, xaml

**My quandary is this:** how does [whatever code that fires off LostFocus event] determine that it no longer has focus when child elements of the content may not be hit test visible?

---

**Semi-relevant backstory**

I've recently started a project to improve upon `Popup`. It sometimes becomes *stuck* open when trying to bind `IsOpen` to `ToggleButton.IsChecked`. Naturally, I began with handling `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`, but these often never worked, and I couldn't reliably force it in code with `Focus()` ("*Attempts* to set focus to this element") if I needed to.

In my adorner-based solution, my first inelegant approach is to capture global MouseDown events in Win32 and determine if the mouse coordinate is within the adorner bounds. However this simply falls apart when some of that content is intended to be **not** hit test visible.

Comment: You don't need any of that. There's a `StaysOpen` property in the `Popup` class that let's you determine whether the popup closes itself when it loses Keyboard Focus.

Comment: @HighCore I realize that, but it's not that simple. This is for a touch interface, by the way. 95% of the time what I had worked fine, but that 5% meant the popup stayed open permanently unless the window itself could lose focus - not possible in a full-screen touch app.

Comment: then I suggest you base your logic on `Keyboard Focus` instead of `Logical Focus` (`LostKeyboardFocus`, etc)

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I don't believe that touch events (or mouse) set keyboard focus. Can it reliably be set in code?

Comment: use `Keyboard.Focus(someleement);` And yes, if you click on a TextBox, which gives you the chance to type on, then that means that Keyboard Focus is now on that TextBox.

Comment: MSDN article on keyboard and logical focus.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx